# MySQL and MFC trapping foreign key errors

Tags: mysql, mfc

I'm developing a program that uses a MySQL Database with some tables with foreign keys. I have the need to let the user delete rows from a table referenced by other tables, but naturally, the DB doesn't let me do this if that row is referenced.

The problem is that when that kind of error happens, the object I use to connect to the DB, gives a nasty error, what I would like to do, is trapping this kind of exception without modify the object, but, if is possible by a query.

Is there a way?

Comment: If you `catch` that exception, in the code which actually invokes the object, you won't have to modify the object!

Comment: The matter is that the object ( CADODatabase ) already catch the exception, what I want to do is to avoid the nasty message that follow the catch, for that particular event. If isn't clear I'll try to edit my question to make it, I'm sorry, but my english is little rusty.